# Windows command line: cannot run a command with a variable as part of its path

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-10, environment-variables

I feel I'm missing something obvious here, but I just can't see it. I have a `cmd` window open, and here's what I run:

```
set QTDIR32=C:\Qt\5.10.1\msvc2015
%QTDIR32%\bin\qmake.exe -v
```

`C:\Qt\5.10.1\msvc2015\bin\qmake.exe` is a valid path to an executable tool.
Expected: the tool's output.
Observed:

> 'C:\Qt\5.10.1\msvc2015' is not recognized as an internal or external
>   command, operable program or batch file.

Tried various combinations of quotes around different parts of the command; tried `start %QTDIR32%\bin\qmake.exe -v` - it opens the 'C:\Qt\5.10.1\msvc2015' folder in Explorer.

`echo %QTDIR32%` prints the expected output.

What am I missing?

Comment: Care to explain the downvotes?

Comment: @Mofi: fair enough, but as I said in the question, it was never a batch file. I opened `cmd.exe` and typed these commands by hand. Then copied them and posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always use double quotes on paths.

```
set "QTDIR32=C:\Qt\5.10.1\msvc2015"
"%QTDIR32%\bin\qmake.exe" -v
```

The reason for double quotes are not always because of spaces between paths, but gets rid of any unwanted whitespace in the actual batch. double quotes are always a good idea.

Comment: Hmm. This shouldn't be necessary here because the path has no spaces, and it shouldn't ever be necessary for the `set` command according to https://ss64.com/nt/set.html. Let me try your suggestion.

Comment: That did it, thank you (the quoted call to `set`). I'm starting to think I've had a stray space in the end of my path when calling `set`.

Comment: Yes, hence the quotes :)

Comment: I see your wisdom now :)